# What is the best way to pass an argument from one subcomponent to other subcomponent?

Tags: react.js

Hi I was just asked by stackoverflow to move this question into this forum (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67685433/how-to-design-the-react-component-properly).

Hi I am pretty new to react and I want to achieve something that turns out to be real pain for me and I am not sure what the best solution might be.

I got an application that handles a single keystore as application keystore and the admin is allowed to upload new keystores and merge the entries of these keystores into the application keystore. This results in the following class definition:

```javascript
export default class ApplicationKeystore extends React.Component
{

    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.scimResourcePath = "/scim/v2/Keystore";
        this.state = {};
        this.setAliasSelectionResponse = this.setAliasSelectionResponse.bind(this);
        this.onAliasSelectionSuccess = this.onAliasSelectionSuccess.bind(this);
    }

    setAliasSelectionResponse(resource)
    {
        let copiedResource = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(resource));
        this.setState({aliasSelectionResponse: copiedResource})
    }

    onAliasSelectionSuccess(resource)
    {
        this.setState({newAlias: resource[ScimConstants.CERT_URI].alias})
    }

    render()
    {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <KeystoreUpload scimResourcePath={this.scimResourcePath}
                                setAliasSelectionResponse={this.setAliasSelectionResponse} />
                <AliasSelection scimResourcePath={this.scimResourcePath}
                                aliasSelectionResponse={this.state.aliasSelectionResponse}
                                onCreateSuccess={this.onAliasSelectionSuccess} />
                <KeystoreEntryList scimResourcePath={this.scimResourcePath}
                                   newAlias={this.state.newAlias} />
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}
```

My problem now occurs on the last component `KeystoreEntryList`. The upload succeeds and the selection of entries to be merged works also correctly (just one at a time not several). But if I successfully merge an entry I get a response with the alias of the keystore entry that should now be added to the state of `KeystoreEntryList`. How do I do this in a clean way. I found several workarounds but all of them are dirty and make the code hard to read...

the important part of the `KeystoreEntryList`can be found here:

```javascript
class KeystoreEntryList extends React.Component
{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.state = {aliases: []};
        this.setState = this.setState.bind(this);
        this.scimClient = new ScimClient(this.props.scimResourcePath, this.setState);
        this.onDeleteSuccess = this.onDeleteSuccess.bind(this);
    }

    async componentDidMount()
    {
        let response = await this.scimClient.listResources();
        if (response.success)
        {
            response.resource.then(listResponse =>
            {
                this.setState({
                    aliases: new Optional(listResponse.Resources[0]).map(val => val.aliases)
                                                                    .orElse([])
                })
            })
        }
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot)
    {
        // TODO if we delete an alias and add the same again the following if condition prevents adding it again
        if (prevProps.newAlias !== this.props.newAlias && this.props.newAlias !== undefined)
        {
            let aliases = this.state.aliases;
            aliases.push(this.props.newAlias);
            aliases.sort();
            this.setState({aliases: aliases, aliasDeleted: undefined});
        }
    }
   ...
}
```

my first idea was to do it on the `componentDidUpdate` method  but this results in the problem stated out by the TODO. Is there any good way how I might be able to smoothly add the new alias into this component?

Comment: Please follow the guidelines: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to **simply state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).